# Keep decimal separator in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I'm trying to upload a table in Excel to MySQL. I changed the decimal separator in my Excel to "." and all the numbers in my table is in point decimal.
However when I upload this data to MySQL using the INSERT INTO function, the decimal separator becomes "," in MySQL. Can anybody help me?

```
trSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" & table1 & "` (`" _
         & field1 & "` " & "varchar(12)" & ",`" _
         & field2 & "` " & "varchar(3)" & ",`" _
         & field3 & "` " & "varchar(4)" & ",`" _
         & field4 & "` " & "varchar(3)" _
         & ")"

conn.Execute strSQL

For i = 1 To 31
val1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 1).Value
val2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 2).Value
val3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 3).Value
val4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 4).Value

stSQL = "INSERT INTO testing (Date, test1 , test2 , test3)"
stSQL = stSQL & "VALUES ('" & val1 & " ',' " & val2 & "','" & val3 & "','" & val4 & "')"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 7).Value = edf

                conn.Execute stSQL
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Text` instead of `.Value`. Value returns the system default decimal separator.

```
val1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 1).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Cstr ou Replace before using value in Insert commande :

```
val1 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 1).Value)
val2 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 2).Value)
val3 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 3).Value)
val4 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 4).Value)
```

or

```
val1 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 1).Value,",",".")
val2 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 2).Value,",",".")
val3 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 3).Value,",",".")
val4 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Cells(i + 38, 4).Value,",",".")
```